# Understanding RStudio's workspace tab lm notation

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, when you create a variable in the workspace, it gets listed in the workspace tab.  For the most part, the information is self-explanatory.  For example, if you make a varialbe `x <- rnorm(10)`, it will say `x numeric[10]`, which means it is a numeric vector of length 10.  However, if you fit a model, e.g., `model <- lm(y~x)`, the workspace will say `model lm[12]`.  Obviously, there is an `lm` object named "model" in the workspace, but what is the `12`?  Moreover, I've noticed that different models (even if all `lm`s) can have different numbers.

Comment: I can delete this question if it's too silly, but I noticed yesterday that the numbers vary, & I realized I don't have any idea what they mean. It's been bugging me ever since.

Comment: For what it's worth a model specified with any categorical predictors (factors) has a `contrasts` element in it, so comes out as length 13 rather than 12 ...

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks. You're right, the numbers were sometimes 12 & sometimes 13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lm`returns a list object (of class `lm`). This list has 12 elements. All this is completely independent from the number of values used in the regression.

```
m <- lm(x1 ~  y1, anscombe)

names(m)
[1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"  "rank"    "fitted.values" "assign"  "qr"           
[8] "df.residual"   "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"         "model"
```

You can access the 'inner' parts of the object using the list element's names, e.g.

```
m$coefficients
(Intercept)          y1 
 -0.9975311   1.3328426
```

To get a feeling for how objects look inside, use the `str` function, e.g. `str(m)`.

Comment: Hmmm, so I guess it could have said `model list{12]` then, if the idea is just that the `lm` model object is simply a list of length 12. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gung, it's not the it is `"simply a list"` but rather, it is **also** a list (in addition to being a linear model).

Comment: @RicardoSaporta To split hairs: It's primarily a list, but also a linear model due to the class attribute.